# Manually enable a device using NetworkManager

Tags: networkmanager

I have this app.  I also have installed NetworkManager.

I have attached 2 wifi dongles to a Raspberry Pi.
When I add a wifi connection i use this:

```
sudo nmcli con add con-name "MyConName1" ifname wlan0 type wifi ssid "My SSID"
sudo nmcli con modify "MyConName1" wifi-sec.key-mgmt wpa-psk
sudo nmcli con modify "MyConName1" wifi-sec.psk "MyPassword"
```

I then add this again to the 2nd wifi dongle:

```
sudo nmcli con add con-name "MyConName2" ifname wlan1 type wifi ssid "My SSID"
sudo nmcli con modify "MyConName2" wifi-sec.key-mgmt wpa-psk
sudo nmcli con modify "MyConName2" wifi-sec.psk "MyPassword"
```

Now my intent is to let MyConName1use my local network only. I do this by modifying the connection:

```
sudo nmcli connection modify "MyConName1" ipv4.never-default true
sudo nmcli connection modify "MyConName1" ipv6.never-default true
```

So, MyConName2 will now default to using the WAN.

This does work. But...

I manually want to start these wifi connections and I do that by using these commands:

```
sudo nmcli con up 'MyConName1'
sudo nmcli con down'MyConName1'
```

etc

However, whilst I can 'see' wlan1' when I use ifconfig of nmcli -show ot does not 'show' 'wlan0'.

In my /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf I have this:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

In my /etc/dhcpcd.conf I do NOT include:

```
denyinterfaces wlan0
denyinterfaces wlan1
```

NB. for both these files I have toggled the true/false with the denyinterfaces.

How can I use nmcli to enable my wlan0 device?

Thanks

Comment: @closer please explain or is this personal?

Comment: This question makes no sense. What OS? You can use NM but it is incompatible with dhcpcd or Debian networking

Comment: @Milliways Thank you for giving your reason.  Raspberry Pi uses a debian based OS and IT does support NM I have been using it for over 4 years now and so have many other developers.  So what is the source of information that tells otherwise?

Comment: http://www.intellamech.com/RaspberryPi-projects/rpi_nmcli.html

Comment: Raspberry Pi DOESN'T use anything it is a piece of hardware that supports many OS

Comment: @Milliways I FAIL to understand your  point here. I have NW installed on Rpi. I am trying to do a particular thing. The answer below allows me to do that. What is your confusion? I said it uses Debian. What is it you do not understand?

Comment: @Milliways the fact that someone DID understand my question and answered as opposed to the 2 closers says a lot to me.

Comment: @pointless site. Too many trolls like yourself. i am quitting this site is it crap

Comment: You referenced dhcpcd which is an incompatible network manager which is the default for Raspberry Pi OS

Comment: @Milliways yes I know all. Sorry looking at how to deregister for this site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I use nmcli to enable my wlan0 device?

You need to use `iproute2` commands to bring UP/DOWN the network interfaces:

```
ip link set wlan0 down
ip link set wlan0 up
```

Then check the device status:

```
nmcli dev status
```

To answer your question, you can use `nmtui` (NetworkManager TUI) to activate/deactivate a network interface:

```
nmtui
```